# Swift dictionary, reading key values - push notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, dictionary, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to display an alert when the user receives a push notification. I use the following code to display the alert. But I don't know how to access the alert of the push notification.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    var state: UIApplicationState = application.applicationState
    if state == UIApplicationState.Active {

        println(userInfo)
        println(userInfo["aps"])

        var alert2 = UIAlertController(title: "Push", message: "Received", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { action in

        }))

        self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert2, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

I thought I just needed to use `userInfo["alert"]` but this just gives me nil. This is what I get in the log.

```
[aps: {
    alert = "Jack sent you a message";
    badge = 1;
}]
Optional({
    alert = "Jack sent you a message";
    badge = 1;
})
```

So this is just me not knowing how to use swift dictionaries. Apologies, but could anyone help

Comment: You should use `userInfo["aps"]["alert"]`. The `alert` key is present under `aps`

Comment: I tried this, but I get  '(NSObject, AnyObject)' does not have a member named 'subscript'

Comment: any update on this? Having similar issue.

Comment: I answered the question below @Arvind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I needed to do was use `(userInfo["aps"] as [NSObject: AnyObject])["alert"]`